# Getting a black preview and a image after onPictureTaken

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I m trying to develop an app which would auto crop the edges of a card which is detected by using opencv.

```
 Here in this function i am doing the following :
```

1) Converting the byte array (ie data) into a bitmap and then to a Mat

2) Cropping the required portion of the card and re sizing it

3) Converting the mat back into a byte array

4) Saving the modified byte array in a File(jpg)

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Mat mat=new Mat();
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, mat);   //converting a mat to bitmap

    Mat matCrop = mat.submat((int)p1.y,(int)p2.y,(int)p3.x,(int)p4.x);//surely no issues here

    Imgproc.resize(matCrop, matCrop, mat.size());

    byte[] imageInBytes = new byte[(int)(matCrop.total() * matCrop.channels())];
    mat.get(0, 0, imageInBytes);
    data=imageInBytes;

            try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mPictureFileName);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {}
```

}

The picture gets saved in memory but the preview as well as the image both are blank . The saved file also takes about 3.5 Mb ,  What could be the reason for this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check if `data==null` in `onPictureTaken` method.

Comment: `BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                            data.length, opts);` try with those lines to decode bitmap from data.

Comment: @ELITE The image gets properly saved , with the taken photo if the first 3 steps are avoided

Comment: add `camera.stopPreview();` and `camera.startPreview();` before `Mat mat=new Mat();` this line..

Comment: @ELITE I m Sorry , both dint work

Comment: @ELITE  I debugged the program and found that the error is in these two lines             byte[] imageInBytes = new byte[(int)(matCrop.total() * matCrop.channels())];
    mat.get(0, 0, imageInBytes);         The bitmap for the above byte array returned NULL